# Have a method directly edit a variable passed as a parameter?

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, methods, parameters

I have a quick question (this is in C#). Let's say I have an array of numbers:

```
int[] count = new int[4] {0, 4, 3, 2};
```

I have a method that does some stuff:

```
public void Invert(int[] arrayVar)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayVar.Count; i++)
    {
        //arrayVar[i] = stuff
    }
 }
```

If I call the method by doing this:

```
Invert(count);
```

Is there a way to have the method directly edit the count array instead of just duplicating it and editing the duplicate? I can't have a global variable for multithreading reasons and I can't return the end result because I have similar methods that have to return very specific things. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: In your given example, the array is not copied. Any edits to `arrayVar` are the same as editing the original `count`.

Comment: Additionally, if you had passed a value type (e.g. `int`), you could use the `ref` keyword to instead pass a reference.

Comment: But if you're truly multi-threading the use of this variable, realize that you're asking how to make this function *not* thread-safe - if two threads call modify this variable, you'll get indeterminate results.  Make sure you look into proper thread safety, e.g. locks or mutexes.

Comment: Jon Skeet has a nice blog that talks about reference vs value types and reference vs value arguments. http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to have the method directly edit the count array instead of just duplicating it and editing the duplicate?

Yes. Do exactly what you are doing. Your program already does exactly what you are asking for.

Arrays are passed *by reference* in C#. `count` and `arrayVar` refer to *the same array*. When you pass an array to a method, that method does not get a copy of the array. It gets a copy of *a reference* to the array.

Changes that you make to `arrayVar` inside `Invert` will also be made to `count` inside the caller because those two variables both contain a *reference* to the same array.

Do not confuse this with the `ref` feature of C#. Ref makes two variables act as though they are *the same variable*.  Here you have two *different* variables that both refer to *the same array*. Make sure that the distinction is clear in your mind.

A number of answers confusingly suggest that you use a list instead of an array.  Lists are also reference types; they have the same semantics as arrays when passed to a method. That is, the passed-in value is a reference.  The reason to use a list instead of an array is because lists are more flexible and powerful than arrays. Arrays are fixed in size; an array with ten elements always has ten elements. A list can have new elements added or old elements removed.

Comment: `Here you have two different variables that both refer to the same array. Make sure that the distinction is clear in your mind` When is the difference important to the average programmer (as opposed to the guy working on the C# compiler)?

Comment: @EricJ.: Two answers. The straightforward answer is: it is very important when the *variable* is the thing being modified. If you modify a variable believing that its alias will be modified, but there is no alias, then you have a bug. The higher-level answer is: by understanding this distinction you know when to use `ref` and why it is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: How about the method calling itself? If the Invert method called itself with arrayVar as the parameter, would the original arrayVar be edited? If I want the original arrayVar to remain remain unchanged after the method calls itself, would I need avoid passing it by reference?

Comment: @user3421896: You need to right now start very carefully distinguishing between **a variable** and **the thing the variable refers to**, because this is the cause of your confusion. If you have two pieces of paper that both say "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue" on them then you have two pieces of paper, but they both refer to the White House.

Comment: @user3421896: To answer your question:  When a method is invoked, *regardless of whether it is invoked recursively*, brand-new variables are created for the formal parameters, and the values of those formals are *copies* of the values of the *arguments*.  So, if Invert calls itself with arrayVar as the argument then you have **two variables both called arrayVar** in flight, and they both contain *the same reference*.

Comment: @user3421896: Your question "what if I want the original arrayVar to remain unchanged?" is unclear because you are not distinguishing between the *variable* arrayVar and the *array that it refers to*.  Which of those two things do you wish to be unchanged?  The *variable* will be unchanged; it will continue to refer to the array it referred to before.  **That array** will have a changed element. **An array is a collection of variables**.

Comment: @user3421896: If what you wish is for *the array* to remain unchanged then an array is the wrong data structure to use. Arrays refer to collections of *variables*, and variables change. You would be better off using an *immutable data type* if you desire the original array to be unchanged.

Comment: @user3421896: The only time in safe C# code where you modify one variable and change the value of another variable is when the variable is marked *ref* or *out*. (There are advanced scenarios in which it is possible to modify variables via other means but you will never run into them in practice.)

Comment: @user3421896: This stuff that you're trying to understand here is *fundamental* to a correct understanding of the language, so you are right to try to get it straight. Jon's article might help. http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Yeah you're right. In the application I am currently coding, I have no idea what is happening although I think it's being caused by something along the lines of what my question asked. Anyways... Thanks guys!